# Authentication Delay Causing Slow URL Update in Next.js Application

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am developing a Next.js application (version 14) using the **create-t3-stack template**. In my homepage, I am using the **getServerAuthSession function** to check if the user is authenticated. If the user is authenticated, I render a table with filtering options. However, I have noticed a significant delay in URL updates when changing filters, leading to slow data fetching.

You can refer this [table](https://shadcn-table-alt.vercel.app/) but this is not checking whether the user is authorized or not

The issue is that when the user is authenticated and I update the URL with new filters, there is a noticeable delay before the URL gets updated and the data is refetched. Even when selecting multiple filters at a time, the url gets updated with only last filter selected. Removing the authentication check results in instant URL updates and quicker data display.

How can I optimize the authentication check to reduce this delay and improve the performance of URL updates when the user is authenticated?